# Problem with AttachmentService of SAP Cloud SDK for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, sap-cloud-sdk

Currently we use SAP REST API for uploading and managing [attachments](https://api.sap.com/api/API_CV_ATTACHMENT_SRV/resource).

We want to replace the standard requests with the SDK because we had problems getting the connection through a `CloudConnector` with the respective proxy settings and because we also use the SDK for all other requests.

```
var attContentSetBuilder = AttachmentContentSet.builder();
attContentSetBuilder.documentInfoRecordDocNumber("10000000008");
attContentSetBuilder.documentInfoRecordDocPart("000");
attContentSetBuilder.documentInfoRecordDocType("YBO");
attContentSetBuilder.documentInfoRecordDocVersion("01");
attContentSetBuilder.businessObjectTypeName("DRAW");
attContentSetBuilder.fileName("TEST.pdf")
attContentSetBuilder.content(fileToBase64("C:\\TEST.pdf"));
var attContentSet = attContentSetBuilder.build();
var requestBuilder = new AttachmentContentSetRequestBuilder();
var contentSetRequester = requestBuilder.create(attContentSet);
contentSetRequester.withCustomHeaders({ key: 'slug', value: 'TEST.pdf' }).execute({XXX}).then ...

function fileToBase64(filename: string): string {
    var fs = require('fs');
    return fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
}
```

Will the content/body with the binary data be set that way? Does the header value `slug` also have to be set? 
Does the Attachment Service also support `GOS`?
So far we get the error:

> "Attachment name cannot be empty"

Answer (score 2):

the error message reads like a message you get from the S/4HANA API, so it seems like there is a semantic problem with your request. Unfortunately, the API Business Hub is not very good in communicating the required fields for a request, but here are some pointers:

1. If you take a look at the entity definition, the following fields are non-nullable:

```
documentInfoRecordDocType: string;
documentInfoRecordDocNumber: string;
documentInfoRecordDocVersion: string;
documentInfoRecordDocPart: string;
logicalDocument: string;
archiveDocumentId: string;
linkedSapObjectKey: string;
businessObjectTypeName: string;
```

so maybe providing values for the ones your missing solves the problem

2. There is [more documentation on this API here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/243e3966d3664ad9adaebe084815d897/1908.500/en-US/2e1be0a60d08400b8e4b1f6b57140a28.html) (I got there by going to the API's page on the Business Hub, clicking on "Details" and then on "Business Documentation" on the bottom of the page)
3. your `.withCustomHeaders` looks off, I'm guessing what you wanted to do is: `.withCustomHeaders({ slug: 'TEST.pdf' })`

Bonus: the builder and request builder have a fluent API, so you can also use it like this:

```
const attContentSet = AttachmentContentSet.builder()
  .documentInfoRecordDocNumber("10000000008")
  .documentInfoRecordDocPart("000")
  .documentInfoRecordDocType("YBO")
  .documentInfoRecordDocVersion("01")
  .businessObjectTypeName("DRAW")
  .fileName("TEST.pdf")
  .content(fileToBase64("C:\\TEST.pdf"))
  .build();
```

That's a matter of taste, of course, personally I find this a little easier to parse mentally.